How can my Blazor method tell if the page it's running on has been navigated away from?
I've got a Blazor page where the user can start a long-running (~10 minute) process that downloads multiple files from a vendor's API, combines them into a zip archive, and downloads the zip archive to the user's computer. Currently, if the user navigates away from the page, the process continues running but I need it to stop.
I originally thought I could use the beforeunload or unload events but everything I've read says to absolutely not use those. (I have almost no JavaScript experience--that's why we're using Blazor.)
How can I either get a notification that the page has been navigated away from or have the process test to see if the page still exists?
Update
I found NavigationManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler which works for page navigation but not for closing a tab or refreshing the page. So I still need a way to find out if the page still exists or not.

You can use JavaScript interop to detect when the user is about to leave the page.. In your Blazor component or service, implement a method to handle the page unload event. Use a CancellationTokenSource to manage the cancellation of the long running process.

@Rena The unload event is deprecated. Its use is strongly discouraged. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

If I read your intent correctly, you can use Dispose on the page and a CancellationToken in the service.
Here's a quick and dirty demo.
A long running scoped service.
public class LongRunningService
{
    public Task RunningTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!RunningTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RunAsync already running");
            return;
        }

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        RunningTask = RunAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("Cancellation Requested");
    }

    public static async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // Fake an asyn process without a cancellation taken
            await Task.Delay(5000);

            if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("RunAsync Cancelled");
                return;
            }

            // if the async process takes a cancellation token
            //await Task.Delay(5000, cancel);

        }
    }
}

My Demo Page:
@page "/"
@implements IDisposable
@inject LongRunningService Service
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.Service.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Service.Stop();
    }
}


Thanks. Dispose wasn't being called but I added the options in this answer and now it's getting called as soon as the tab is closed or the page is refreshed.
